# Is there a faster way to move pictures by a PowerShell script

Tags: performance, powershell

I want to move all pictures from several folders to one destination folder, if they listed in my txt-file.

The script works, but there are about 81k pictures and 450k names (eg `samlpe-green-bigpic-detail-3.jpg`) in the txt-file, it is damn slow.

Is there a way to script it, so it works faster?

```cs
$qpath     = "c:\sample\picz\"
$Loggit    = "c:\sample\pic_move.log"
$txtZeileU = "c:\sample\names.txt"
$d_pic     = "C:\sample\moved_picz"

$arrZeileU = Get-Content -Path $txtZeileU
foreach ($Zeile in $arrZeileU) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $qpath -Recurse |
        where {$_.Name –eq $Zeile} |
        Move-Item -Destination $d_pic -Verbose -Force *>&1 |
        Out-File -FilePath $Loggit -Append
}
```

Comment: robocopy would be faster but I do not know how to integrate that with your input process. Depending on your PowerShell Version running though the whole folder looking for one file for every file you have is very slow.

Comment: Why do you have 450k names when there are only 81k pictures?

Comment: Have you considered using a module for parallel pipelines? For instance, Start-Parallel or Split-Pipeline?

Comment: I am with @AnsgarWiechers, How do you have 450k names but only 81k pictures?

Comment: Your approach is inefficient, you read in the file with the names and for every name you do the gci (450k*81k), instead of doing the gci and compare against the already in memory text file.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ack, just 450k-1 times too often.